# Does Worcestershire Sauce go Bad?

Tags: fermentation

I really like Worcestershire sauce on a few things, but I never use it that often.

My question is simply, does it ever go bad, and should I try to use it up quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real Worcestershire sauce has a very long shelf life, many many years

Some people even age it, in a dark cellar!

Be warned though, many brands of Worcestershire style sauce are not actually Worcestershire sauce, they are just sugar with flavourings, no sign of rotten fish etc :-(

See [What are the key ingredients in Worcester Sauce?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25889/what-are-the-key-ingredients-in-worcester-sauce)

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely it is a sauce made from a vinegar base and that imparts enough acidity to the sauce that spoiling bacteria won't grow.